# UIView to another View in objective C

Tags: iphone, uiview

when i goto the next view support in UIView based application, i have to goto

```
secondView * = [[secondView alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"ani" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.9];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view addSubview:secondView.view];
```

my question is that i can't release the secondView because my object are remove on the same view.. if i can't and goto the second view the how and when to release the secondView object and in which view .. because i also have to come back from the secondView to the firstView like that.. i write the back code:

```
[self.View removefromsuperview]; // means this code is written on second View backbutton then its goto the firstView..
```

I want to know that when i release the secondView object which i create the in the firstView... i don't use autorealease because its very bad ...

i also think the one solution that could i release the secondView object in the firstView dealloc Class .. please help me..

thanks.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking exactly...

Comment: i am asking when to release the secondView object which i create in the first View ... thats all .. simply .. and what is the best possibilities .. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `initWithNibName` and `.view` suggest that `secondView` is an instance of a UIViewController subclass. If that's the case then you should not be adding one UIViewController's view as a subview of another UIViewController's view. Doing so is [abusing UIViewControllers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) and will result in unexpected behavior in your app.

If you want to manage transitions between views you should either use one of Apple's provided container view controllers to manage multiple UIViewControllers or swap between subviews of a single UIViewController's view.
Either way your controller could be released by whichever parent controller is managing the transition between views. For example if you were using a UINavigationController it could release a controller when it is popped off the navigation stack. If you wrote your own UIViewController to manage multiple views, each of which might have a non-UIViewController controller, then you could release a view and it's controller from that parent view controller when the sub view is no longer needed. Let parent objects manage their children.

Comment: i am not understanding your answer too much .. :(